# Por que me imprime esto?

Tags: c#

Soy nuevo en la programcion y estoy viendo herencias pero no se por que en el output me  sale El nombre es :Rojo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MiClaseAutomovil
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //vehiculo P = new vehiculo ("Bocho","Rojo",2018,"dsaw2");

            Piloto Pilot = new Piloto(20,"Mexico");
```

**Clases**

```
public class vehiculo
{

    private string marca;
    private string color;
    private int modelo;
    private string placa;

    public string Marca
    {
        get { return marca; }
        set { marca = value; }
    }

    public string Color
    {
        get { return color; }
        set { color = value; }
    }

    public int Modelo
    {
        get { return modelo; }
        set { modelo = value; }
    }

    public string Placa
    {
        get { return placa; }
        set { placa = value; }
    }



    public vehiculo(string marca, string color, int modelo, string placa)
    {
        this.marca = marca;
        this.color = color;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.placa = placa;
    }

    public vehiculo(string marca, string color, byte modelo, string placa)
    {
        this.marca = marca;
        this.color = color;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.placa = placa;
    }
}
```

**Clase 2 **

```
public class Piloto:vehiculo
{


    private int años;
    private string ciudad;


    //constructor

    public Piloto(string marca, string color, int modelo, string placa, int años,string ciudad) : base(marca, color, modelo,placa)
    {
        this.años = años;
        this.ciudad = ciudad;

    }

    public int CantMat { get => años; set => años = value; }
    public string Ciudad { get => ciudad; set => ciudad = value; }
}
```

Comment: como lograste instancia la clase `Piloto` indicando solo 2 parametros en el constructor? porque en el codigo que muestras hay 6, deberias tener un error en la compilacion

Comment: El código que envias no esta completo, ya que no aparece la parte en la que imprime el mansaje. Como no hay ninguna propiedad nombre en ninguna de las dos clases, seguramente el fallo este ahí, en la cadena que indica lo que estas imprimiendo. No estas imprimiendo el nombre del piloto (para el cual no existe la propiedad) sino el color de su vehiculo. Aparte para que compile, debes pasarle 6 parametros al constructor de Piloto.